# Windows 8 x64 and the Renesas USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller

Tags: windows-8, usb-3

Laptop Lenovo W520 with 2 USB 3.0 ports.

I have issues with the "Renesas USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller" which got installed automatically with Windows 8.
When the device is marked as working in the Device Manager (no yellow triangle on the corresponding icon), the USB 3.0 ports work, but only if both of them aren't in use.
If i try to use both of them, either ports stop working or they do so very sluggishly - using a mouse is a chore.

Sometimes, after a reboot, none of the ports work and the "Renesas USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller" is marked with a yellow triangle in the device manager. Log info says, that the device has stopped working.

Comment: try to install the Windows 7 drivers and not the generic Windows 8 ones.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a USB 3.0 controller with NEC (Renesas) chip that presents this same problem. I tried several things but nothing worked 100%.

For me it helps most of the time (not always) when i use Windows 8 default driver for this chip and FULLY shut down Windows. Only after a full shutdown i have the chance that the driver works.

I created a shortcut on my desktop with the following target to perform a full shutdown:

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /s /t 0
```